# is it possible to limit the network traffic from my PC to my PC?

Tags: networking, tcp, traffic

Hi Guys I'm debugging some CS program and to view the performance of the application in slow internet I tried many different ways. However the best would be the Server and the client be in the same PC ---- my debugging environments for both the server side and the client is setup in one PC.

So I'm wondering is there anyway to limit the speed? I'm using TCP but I don't know too much in-depth knowledge of it.

Thank you

Comment: Are you talking about http traffic, or like any kind of tcpip traffic?

Comment: I'm using TCP, so yes it's TCPIP traffic.

Comment: What operating system are you using on your desktop? Most versions of Linux and BSD will do this out of the box.

Comment: @symcbean I use windows, and I found http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/socket_sniffer.html does the magic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found this does what I need.

http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/socket_sniffer.html
Captures Windows Socket traffic, no matter it's local or not.

Answer (score 1):

There are two important factors regarding a "slow" internet connection that you need to test out since they have different implications for your application: bandwidth and latency.

If you provide some more details about what os you are running your tests on, it would be easier to recommend a way to limit the network performance.

On a related side note, it's generally a bad idea to performance test any kind of networking using the loopback device on your machine, since many aspects of this will perform very different than the regular network device on your machine.

Comment: You have inspired me, it would be pretty cool to write a network delay simulator that would accept IP packets then delay them, say 80ms (the one-way trip time between New Zealand and the USA), before forwarding them on. Could be a great unix-land tool.

Comment: Absolutely, ping me when you have a beta :-D

Comment: Well I'm using Windows XP. And i'll be very happy to have the BETA too :)

Comment: @PP indeed it could be, in fact it is, it's name is NetEm, short for Network Emulator.

Answer (score 0):

You mention in the comments this needs to be done on windows, while the Network Emulators I know of (e.g. netem, TCN, other variants) all require Linux. So one thing you could do is create a virtual machine (VirtualBox is fine, I did similar things with it), install linux on it, configure 2 network interfaces, emulate the slow/long/lossy/jittery network between them, and route the test traffic through it from windows.

Comment: Finally I found this: http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/socket_sniffer.html, capture windows socket traffic without any additional configuration.